# Delete ALL rows from TABLE using ContentResolver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

How can we delete all rows from an Android Table using the `ContentResolver`?

I have tried:

1. `context.getContentResolver().delete(Abcd.CONTENT_URI, null, null);`
2. `context.getContentResolver().delete(Abcd.CONTENT_URI, "1", null);`

And I know my uri is correct as when I give a condition as :

`context.getContentResolver().delete(Channel.CONTENT_URI, "name = ?", "abcd");`
the code works.

What is the correct way to delete all?

Right now I am using a hack: `context.getContentResolver().delete(Channel.CONTENT_URI, "name != ?", "");` as name can never be empty.

But I would like to know the best way possible.

Comment: what you want to delete please specify.

Comment: getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(com.example.sales.CONTENT_URI, null,null);    will delete all the row from ContentResolver

Comment: so it is your custom `ContentProvider`, post `delete` method then

Answer (score 2):

Please use,

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(CONTENT_URI, null, null);
```